# JQuery pass variable through 2 functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, radio-button

In JQuery, I have this first function **superClientChoose** that is a switch. When the switch content is loaded, in the screen you see some input radios. 
As you can see, if I click one radio tf goes to another function **mainMenuManagement** and I pass the variable "option", but...

The problem is that when I try to do an alert with the option value in the second function, I don't get the correct value. I need to get either superMarket or client, but I get the URL where the index.html is, inseide my computer...!!

file:///media/ (...) /index.html#

What am I doing wrong?

```js
function superClientChoose(option)
{
 $("#mainMenu").hide();

 switch (option)
 {
  case "superMarket":
    $("div#mainMenu").show();

    var divContent="<br><b>Click the option to run</b><br/>";
    divContent+="<form id='superForm'> <input type='radio' name='options' id='stockEntry' onClick='mainMenuManagement("+option+")'/> Client entry";
    divContent+="<br/>";
    divContent+="<input type='radio' name='options' id='stockModify' onClick='mainMenuManagement("+option+")'/> Client modification"; 
    
    divContent+="</form><br/>";

    $("#mainMenu").html(divContent); 
    break;
  case "client":
    $("div#mainMenu").show();

    var divContent="<br><b>Click the option to run</b><br/>";
    divContent+="<form id='superForm'> <input type='radio' name='options' id='clientEntry' onClick='mainMenuManagement("+option+")'/> Client entry";
    divContent+="<br/>";
    divContent+="<input type='radio' name='options' id='clientModify' onClick='mainMenuManagement("+option+")'/> Client modification"; 
    divContent+="</form><br/>";

    $("#mainMenu").html(divContent);   
    break; 
  default:
   alert("Option is not correct: "+option);
   break;
 }
}
```

Here is where I get the problem with option2.

```js
function mainMenuManagement(option2)
{
 var option2;
 var chosenIdSC=$('input[name=options]:checked', '#superForm').attr("id");
 
 alert(option2); //this one takes the INCORRECT value
alert("cSC: "+chosenIdSC); //this one takes the correct value
  
 // ... more and more code here...
```

Comment: If i remove var option2, I get the same problem.

Comment: is your 1st option works properly? and are you getting correct DIV contents on 2nd option?

Comment: Yes,in the 1rt function, the variable option works perfect.

Comment: i suggest to change onClick='mainMenuManagement("+option+")'  to  onClick='mainMenuManagement(\""+option+"\")'  or  onClick='mainMenuManagement("client")'
try with direct value passing. to check..

Comment: HackerGK is correct, you should a get an js error like 'superMarket' is not defined when you click on the radio button, because you do not pass a string but a non existing variable named superMarket or client.

Comment: You are right,  HackerGK. Adding the 2 \ solved the problem. :D (\""+option+"\")